# Unable to attach call logs for opportunity with out ownership access

Tags: attachment, sharing, notes, organization-wide

Hi friends in my organisation org-wide defaults for opportunity is Private.

But some users have acess view all opportunities,read access and create access.

But if they want to attach calls they need to change the ownership to there name and uploading the attchments.

Is there any possibility to provide access to upload notes with out having edit access to the opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

If you have chatter enabled, any user can attach a file via chatter feed.

These files will display in the notes and attachments list just like the ones attached from the related list.

If you switch to using files, I believe any user w read access can attach a file directly via the files related list, and it's a better experience, so consider making the switch.  It's also needed for Lightning.